# Can every vector be written in linear combination of eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues, when $\mathrm{T}$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, diagonalization

If $\mathrm{T}$ is a linear operator on $\mathrm{V}$, and $\mathrm{T}$ is also diagonalizable, does it hold that,

> Every vector of $\mathrm{V}$ can be written in a linear combination of
> eigenvectors of $\mathrm{T}$ with distinct eigenvalues.

I know that every vector can be written in a linear combination of eigenvectors, if diagonalizable.
However, I'm not sure whether it still holds when the eigenvectors are with distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: This is clearly not true without additional assumptions! What if you don't even have any eigenvalues/eigenvectors? Consider the zero map, or the rotation of Euclidean space by, say, 30 degrees.

Comment: Seems like you mean to ask the question assuming diagonalisability. Might wanna add that to the question body. (Not just in the title)

Comment: When $T$ is diagonalizable it is true.

Comment: @YiFan Right, I missed it accidentally. Thanks :)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks, I get it. Perhaps I've been misunderstanding some key concepts of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(If $T$ is diagonalizable), every vector is even a *sum* of eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues: if $v=∑_ix_iv_i$ with $v_i$ eigenvector for eigenvalue $λ_i$, then $v=∑_λu_λ$ with $u_λ=∑_{λ_i=λ}x_iv_i$, i.e. you group within $u_λ$ all $x_iv_i$'s corresponding to the eigenvalue $λ$.